# How SSH proxy works?

Tags: ssh, proxy, unix, port-forwarding

I'm trying to map local ports in order to redirect traffic to proxy server.
I got instruction containing this command:

```
ssh -A -t -l root 106.120.124.39 -L :8888:106.120.102.53:8888
```

From `SSH` manual:

`-A`

> Enables forwarding of the authentication agent connection. This can also be specified on a per-host basis in a configuration file.
>
> Agent forwarding should be enabled with caution. Users with the
>   ability to bypass file permissions on the remote host (for the agent’s
>   UNIX-domain socket) can access the local agent through the forwarded
>   connection. An attacker cannot obtain key material from the agent,
>   however they can perform operations on the keys that enable them to
>   authenticate using the identities loaded into the agent.

`-t`

> Force pseudo-terminal allocation

`-L`

> Specifies that connections to the given TCP port or Unix socket on the
>   local (client) host are to be forwarded to the given host and port, or
>   Unix socket, on the remote side.

Despite reading this I don't understand how it really works and what are implications of typing this in terminal. Can someone explain this in *simple* terms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought I had a graphic illustration on `-L :9990:198.51.100.0:9999` somewhere 
 and [I did](https://serverfault.com/questions/842365/how-to-ssh-tunnel-with-keys/842394)!

[image: Difference between <code>example.com</code> and <code>localhost</code> on the remote side.]

The diagram visualizes a situation, where the `-L [ bind_address:]port:host:hostport` is used to access resource on remote side. Now, you can connect to port `9990` on your SSH client computer as if you were connecting to `example.com:9999` *from* the SSH server. Destination could be anything. I didn't want to use your `8888` on both sides to avoid confusion; it can be a different port.

A picture is worth a thousand words; half of the 2000 words in [How to Use SSH Tunneling](https://www.howtogeek.com/168145/how-to-use-ssh-tunneling/)

Comment: It really does. I used to read that article as well; and it was confusing as hell the first time before I find some graphical illustrations like the one above.

Answer (score 1):

I think SSH.com has a pretty simple and well-written [explanation](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example) about SSH tunneling / forwarding.

In case of the `-t` flag, [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-purpose-of-a-pseudo-tty) is another good read; and [here](https://yakking.branchable.com/posts/ssh-A/) is the one for the `-A` flag.

**A picture might explain the situation better (`-D` = Dynamic Forwarding):**

[image: SSH Forwarding Graph]